# Output string after evaluating numbers in int

Tags: java

I'm currently trying to print a string for each instance of 3 specific numbers (3 to Pim, 5 to Pam, 7 to Pum) in a number that might be present after user input (EX: Input: 1052373 Output: PamPimPumPim). I tried converting the number to a string and using .contains method but it isn't working. The other part of the code checks if the number is divisible by 3, 5 or 7 and outputs in the same way, and it works fine.
Help's appreciated!

```
package pimpampum;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PIMPAMPUM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduza um número:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();
        String y = x.toString();
         if(x % 3==0){
             System.out.print("Pim");
        }
         if(x % 5==0){
                 System.out.print("Pam");
        } 
         if(x % 7==0){
                 System.out.print("Pum");
        }
         if(y.contains("3")){
                 System.out.print("Pim");
        }
         if(y.contains("5")){
                 System.out.print("Pam");
        }
         if(y.contains("7")){
                 System.out.print("Pum");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you hear about the 'else if'?

Comment: I tried using it but for some reason only the first division would be checked, so if it was dividable by both 3 and 5, would only output Pim.

Comment: iterate the string, check each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print appropriate word for digits 3, 5, or 7 contained in the input number, just iterate the characters upon converting the number into a String:

```
int x = input.nextInt();
String y = String.valueOf(x);
for (char c : y.toCharArray()) {
    String code = switch(c) {
        case '3' -> "Pim";
        case '5' -> "Pam";
        case '7' -> "Pum";
        default  -> "";
    };
    System.out.print(code);
}
System.out.println();
```

For the input `1052373`, the code above prints:

```
PamPimPumPim
```

for `..5.373`, the rest digits are ignored.

Comment: Hi, could you post all the code used? for some reason it's giving me a ton of errors when I try it.

Comment: Nevermind, reopened the project on the IDE and apparently it works now lol. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is a While to iterate the numbers.

I present my solution to your problem.

From what I understand about your question, the additions I made to your code seem to me to be adequate for that.

I would like to point out that a little Google search would quickly solve your problems.

Anyway, we are here to share and help each other!

If this is the intended Up Vote.

Any questions, ask or comment!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Introduza um número:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        x = input.nextInt();
        String y = String.valueOf(x);

        LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        while(x > 0){
            stack.push(x % 10);
            x = x / 10;
        }

        while ((!stack.isEmpty())){
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }

         if(x % 3==0){
             System.out.print("Pim");
        }
         if(x % 5==0){
                 System.out.print("Pam");
        } 
         if(x % 7==0){
                 System.out.print("Pum");
        }
         if(y.contains("3")){
                 System.out.print("Pim");
        }
         if(y.contains("5")){
                 System.out.print("Pam");
        }
         if(y.contains("7")){
                 System.out.print("Pum");
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Introduza um número:
1052373
1
0
5
2
3
7
3
PimPamPumPimPamPum
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Using `String y = String.valueOf(x);` instead of `String y = x.toString();` partially does what I want since it prints once if the number is present, but still not all iterations of it. Unfortunately the loop isn't working as intended, since it is outputing PimPamPum regardless of the number, and isn't printing according to all the iterations. It has something to do with the first while loop and I can't really understand why since I'm not sure what it's doing besides pushing whatever value of x it gets to into the stack.